# Makefile/C++ Classes: Makefile error for C++? Or maybe class definition error?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to make a Makefile, but don't quite understand how it works, and therefore can't really debug it, and add the proper things in it.

I have a total of three files. My "main" file:

> valid_board.cpp

and then I have a .h and a .cpp file that define a class:

> xword_puzzle.h
>
> xword_puzzle.cpp

In *xword_puzzle.cpp* I wrote `#include "xword_puzzle.h"` , in *xword_puzzle.h*, I wrote `#pragma once`, and in *valid_board.cpp* I wrote `#include "xword_puzzle.h"`. Despite this, when I run my Makefile, it doesn't seem to be properly including the class I have defined in the xword_puzzle files.

I have this as a makefile that compiles just the main file.

```
# the compiler: gcc for C program, define as clang++ for C++
CXX=clang++

# compiler flags:
#  -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
#  -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Werror -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG

# the build target executable:
TARGET = valid_board

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

EXAMPLE OF ERROR:
In *xword_puzzle.cpp* I define the class

```
Puzzle::Puzzle(char** xword, int rows, int cols) { ...
```

but then in * valid_board.cpp* I attempt to type

```
Puzzle* asdf_puz = new Puzzle(puzzle, 15, 15);
```

and get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Puzzle::Puzzle(char**, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in valid_board-c21998.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It should be noted that currently my *xword_puzzle.h* contains

```
class Puzzle {
public:
  Puzzle(char** xword, int rows, int cols);


  private:

    vector<string> accrosses;
    vector<string> downs;

};
```

and when I remove `public:` the error changes to

```
valid_board.cpp:54:28: error: calling a private constructor of class 'Puzzle'
    Puzzle* asdf_puz = new Puzzle(puzzle, 15, 15);
                           ^
./xword_puzzle.h:15:3: note: implicitly declared private here
  Puzzle(char** xword, int rows, int cols);\
  ^
```

which leads me to belive that the error might be elsewhere.

Comment: Your makefile needs to also compile "xword_puzzle.cpp", currently it's only compiling "valid_board.cpp"

Comment: @UnholySheep how do I change my makefile so that xword_puzzle.cpp is also compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting `Undefined symbols for architecture` means that `linker` - a program to 'assemble' an executable from multiple obj files - can not find 'implementation' of `Puzzle::Puzzle(char**, int, int)` - but this implementation is required. Not you do have implementation in `xword_puzzle.cpp` but you don't `tell` linker to use it:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp
```

this line will be interpreted as:

```
clang++ -g -std=c++11 -Werror -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -o valid_board valid_board.cpp
```

- which means compile 'valid_board' from `valid_board.cpp`.

I suggest you check http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ as it gives an example close to your use case:

```
CXX=clang++

# compiler flags:
#  -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
#  -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Werror -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG

# the build target executable:
TARGET = valid_board

DEPS = xword_puzzle.h
OBJ = valid_board.o xword_puzzle.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: How would I go about implementing that? What does that mean?

Comment: I have update my answer with an example how to change it.